# how to make phpmailer code more simple it use to send 2 mails

Tags: php

I have php code using phpmailer to send two different messages to two users. I have duplicate the code twice to send both mails, but that's makes the process takes long tome to complete the task. is there any solution to make my code more simple

//// --------------------   send email. to student adviser ----------------------------------------------------------
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

```
$mail->Username = "rms@gmail.com"; 
$mail->Password = "12121212"; 
$mail->AddAddress($advisoremail);
$mail->FromName = "RMS-NCT";

$mail->Subject = "New Request from: ".$_SESSION['UID'];
$mail->Body    = "Dear Mr. Adviser you have got new request from 26s12115 ... click here to access it. http://localhost/rms/"; 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; 
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->From = $mail->Username;
if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else
    echo "Message has been sent";
```

// ------------send email to student ----------------------

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Username = "rms@gmail.com"; // your GMail user name
$mail->Password = "12121212"; 
$mail->AddAddress($_SESSION['UEMAIL']);
$mail->FromName = "RMS-NCT";

$mail->Subject = "Receipt for your new Request";
$mail->Body    = "Dear Student .. Your request has been sent.. you will get response as soon as possible."; 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->From = $mail->Username;
if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else
    echo "Message has been sent";
```

Comment: What is not simple here? the code is very readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you have two different subjects and bodies, I would say no. There is no way to simplify this task.
But you could put the task in one function, that gets the different parameters. So you just have one function to call.

```
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php"); 

function send_mail($email, $subject, $body) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->Username = "rms@gmail.com"; 
    $mail->Password = "12121212"; 
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->FromName = "RMS-NCT";

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $body; 
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    $mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; 
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->From = $mail->Username;
    if(!$mail->Send())
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    else
        echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for your help. I have done as your change but still the process takes long time to finish the task .  why??

Comment: This is not an optimization for faster run times. Just for a better reading of the code. How long does it take? Is it only send to 2 email addresses, or to more than 2?

Comment: it sends to 2 emails only and it takes 15 seconds

Comment: 15 seconds seems a long time. But I don't know how long the respond time to the external mail server is. On the other hand, you could try to create the `$mail = new PHPMailer()` out of the `send_mail` method and put it also as parameter.

Comment: Still I got the same problem. I think I have to change phpmailer.

Answer (score 0):

```
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
function sendMail($to = "trash@domain.com", $subject = "", $body = "", $from = "RMS-NCT")
{
     $mail = new PHPMailer();
     $mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
     $mail->Port = 465;
     $mail->IsSMTP();
     $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
     $mail->Username = "rms@gmail.com";
     $mail->Password = "12121212";

     $mail->From = $mail->Username;
     $mail->FromName = $from;
     $mail->AddAddress($to);
     $mail->Subject = $subject;
     $mail->Body = $body;

     if(!$mail->Send()) {
          return false;
     }

     return true;
}
```

In code, smth like this:

```
$Address = $advisoremail;
$Subject = "New Request from: " . $_SESSION['UID'];
$Body = "Dear Mr. Adviser ...";
if (sendMail($Address, $Subject, $Body)) {
    echo "Message has been sent";
} else {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```